# Jquery script - Make Div visible on button click

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code

http://jsfiddle.net/BQUyT/

**- On my side i have the following in my Head:**

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $("p").toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**And this as my HTML:**

```
<a id="button" href="#">Show/Hide</a>
<div id="item">Item</div>
```

How do i make another botton, and another DIV that doesn't react on the previous button click

I want 1 to make Item 1 disapear / visible And i want 2 to make Item 2 Diapear / visible, how is that possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/BQUyT/211/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't use same **ID** multiple times. Instead you can use **CLASS**.
    HTML:

```
<a class="button" href="#">1</a>
<div class="item">Item 1</div>

<a class="button" href="#">2</a>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>

JS:

 $( ".button" ).click(function() {
    var index=$( ".button" ).index( this );
    $('.item').eq(index).toggle();
 });
```

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/BQUyT/221/

Comment: very much hard coding.

Comment: This is a very complicated (and inefficient) way of saying "just toggle the next item" ...

Comment: @user3442766 no, it really isn't!  See comment above.  It unnecessarily tries to retrieve and count both the number of `button` elements and the number of `item` elements on every click, when it's utterly trivial given your DOM to identify the next `item` given the adjacent `.button`.

Comment: What does that mean, since you say it really isn't i suppose that this is not what i want, let me upload the site. And show where its supposed to be used.

Comment: I mean that whilst this code appears to do what you need, it does it in an extremely suboptimal manner.  Heck, it's not even the shortest code!

Answer (score 1):

1. ID's must be unique
2. If you want multiple elements to act the same, give them a `class` (e.g. `button`).
3. `$('.button').on('click', function() { $(this).next().toggle() });`

The latter just says "when an element with class "button" is clicked, toggle the visibility state of the next element found in the DOM"

NB: I've used `.on('click')` rather than `.click()` because in our coding guidelines I consider `.click` deprecated, even if the jQuery devs themselves haven't.  `.click` causes confusion because it can both *register* a handler and *trigger* a handler.  Instead, we always use the explicit `.on` for the former and `.trigger` for the latter.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/BQUyT/217/

Comment: downvoter - please explain!  Or is this just a revenge downvote because I've downvoted a couple of _poorly coded, inefficient_ answers?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery toggleClass to add and remove a CSS-class which hides or shows the #item div.

**CSS**

```
#item.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$( "#button" ).on('click', function() {
    $( "#item" ).toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

Updated jsfiddle
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/BQUyT/212/)

Comment: jQuery's `.toggle` is better for portable animations than `.toggleClass` - the latter can only provide smooth transitions when combined with CSS effects.

Comment: http://secure.securehome.nu/proddigi.aspx

This is what i wanna use it for, so you can expand and check informations about a product, is there any other way / better way to make that happen :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some 'errors' in your html and script.

First the id's in your html must be unique. Use class instead.

```
<a class="button" href="#">1</a>
<div class="item">Item 1</div>

<a class="button" href="#">2</a>
<div class="item">Item 2</div>
```

On click, toggle the next element

```
$( ".button" ).click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BQUyT/213/)